# Is continuity necessary for using the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on the integral of the partial derivative of a bivariate function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Let $G(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a differentiable function everywhere, and $G_1(x,y)$ be its partial derivative with respect to the first argument at $(x,y)$. Define $H(x)=\int_0^x G_1(t,t)dt.$ I have three questions:

(1) Is the differentiability of $G$ everywhere sufficient to guarantee that $H$ is well defined? (i.e. is it sufficient to guarantee $G_1(t,t)$ is Riemann integrable.)

(2) If $H$ is well defined, is the differentiability of $G$ everywhere sufficient to guarantee that $H'(x)=G_1(x,x)$?

(3) If the answer to one or both of the previous questions is no, what do I need to assume for $H$ to be well defined and $H'(x)=G_1(x,x)$? (I know that it is sufficient to assume that $G_1(t,t)$ is continuous in $[0,x]$, but I would hope for a weaker condition).

Question was edited for clarity.

Comment: I can't see what you mean by "Note that it only needs to be well defined at a specific value $x$".

Comment: I mean that I'm only interested in the local result for a specific value of $x$. Thus, if in order for $H(x)$ to be well defined and $H'(x)=G_1(x,x)$ exactly at $x$ I only need, say, local continuity of $G_1(t,t)$ in a neighborhood of $x$, I would like to know. I tried to improve that note.

Comment: Of course you need the integrand to be (Riemann) integrable. But to differentiate $H$ at $x$, you need the integrand to be continuous *at* $x$.

Comment: Ted, my question is whether anything needs to be assumed in the context I described. I know that the first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus requires continuity, but that is (1) a stronger result than I need, since I only need the differentiability at the upper limit of the integral, and (2) I am integrating  the partial derivative of $G$ through a specific path. Considering that the function $G$ is differentiable everywhere, is this enough?

Comment: @TonyK $G$ is continuous, but $G_1(t,t)$ may not be continuous.

Comment: So, if the derivative is unbounded, $H$ won't even be defined as a Riemann integral. Take a variant of the standard example, $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x^2), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$.

Comment: @adalaio: Oh yes, I didn't notice the subscript. Comment removed

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, so it seems that $G_1(t,t)$ bounded is a necessary condition.